# What is a specific word for "loving a friend"?

Tags: verbs, phrase-requests

In Italian, "to love someone" has two translations:

- *amare qualcuno*, meaning "to desire a romantic relationship with someone";
- *voler bene a qualcuno*, meaning "to care for someone" (literally: "to wish for someone's good") - for example, "*to love* a friend" is translated as "*voler bene a* un amico".

I don't know of any word in English which is as strong as "to love", yet cannot be misunderstood for interest in a romantic relationship. Is there such a phrase?

So far, the best I came up with is "to care for someone", but it doesn't express the same strength, so to speak, as "to love [a friend]".

Comment: Yes, "to care" is the best I could find for such context and what I usually use when I think that *voglio bene a qualcuno*.

Comment: In a completely informal slang sense, you may use the word ["frove"](https://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=Frove&amp=true&defid=1617482). Yes, it's not a _real_ word yet, that's why I'm leaving this in a comment. **I frove you!**

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to go with "no". We live in ambiguity of the many meanings of "love" in English, or if we need to be specific we resort to similes or explanations: "I love you like a [sister/friend/parent]".

Answer (score 0):

We don't have a special word for this. When we need to distinguish it, we say something like like: I love you, but I'm not *in love* with you.

*In love* refers to strong, romantic affection.

Answer (score 0):

I think Americans use the conjunction 'but' to distinguish brotherly sentiment from romantic love or employ slang: 'Love ya bro'

Answer (score 0):

To love someone as a friend can be considered as **platonic** love.

Comment: Please elaborate on your answer, with perhaps examples of usage and corroboration.

Answer (score 0):

In American English, if we love someone as a friend, we usually say that we [**like**](http://www.wordcentral.com/cgi-bin/thesaurus) that person.

- I **like** Gladys because she is a faithful and kindhearted friend.